# Eclipse - location of breakpoints is messed up when I add or remove code and recompile

Tags: eclipse

I am a long-time user of Visual Studio who recently started using Eclipse. In Eclipse, I have noticed that when I set a breakpoint, it is locked to that exact 'line number'. So if I add or delete code above it, the breakpoint is no longer located in the correct place - it's at the same line number but not the same instruction. For example, if it was inside an 'if' statement, it may now be outside that 'if' statement. In VS, the breakpoint line numbers automatically move up and down if you add or delete lines of code above.

Is there a way to set Eclipse so that the breakpoint locations move up and down with changes in the code, like in VS?

I am using C++ and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

Comment: In what language? The rules for how breakpoints move around with changes and whether it's done correctly can vary from language to language and editor to editor.

Comment: I have modified the question to state that I am using C++ and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.